# How do i code to trigger a save operation by press of Keyboard key F2?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm building this simple POS app, what I want to do is on what control the focus is as long as the form is open, when I press F2 it should call the "Save()" (this is not a event call but a method call) to save transaction.

thanks

Comment: Can you please share your code that handles key events and performs the save?

Comment: "on what control the focus is"...does this mean that there are different `Save` calls to deal with?  Or just one `Save` for the Form, regardless of focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on KeyPreview on your form to catch key presses for all its children. Then just handle the form's KeyDown event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can use the KeyEventArgs parameter to determine if the key was F2. Then just call your save method.